# How to access JSON Object name/value?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

```
function (data) {
    //add values based on activity type
    //data = JSON.parse(data);
    //alert(abc.Phone1);

    alert(data.myName)

    alert(data.toString());
    if (activityType == "Phone") {
    }
    return;

},
```

As you can see this callback function of `$.ajax` taking `JSON` data from controller.

For example:

`[{"name":"myName" ,"address": "myAddress" }]`

In this case my first alert giving me undefined and second/third alert popup comes up with:

`[{"name":"myName" ,"address": "myAddress" }]`

How can I access value by name so that my first alert filled out with `myName` which is value of `name`?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In stead of parsing JSON you can do like followng:

```
$.ajax({
  ..
  dataType: 'json' // using json, jquery will make parse for  you
});
```

To access a property of your JSON do following:

```
data[0].name;

data[0].address;
```

---

Why you need `data[0]` because data is an array, so to its content retrieve you need `data[0]` (first element), which gives you an object `{"name":"myName" ,"address": "myAddress" }`.

And to access property of an object rule is:

```
Object.property
```

or sometimes

```
Object["property"] // in some case
```

So you need

`data[0].name` and so on to get what you want.

---

#### If you not

set `dataType: json` then you need to parse them using `$.parseJSON()` and to retrieve data like above.

Comment: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=20,77&sensor=false  from this url how should get "formatted_address" field value in a variable?                                   success : function(data) { address = data['formatted_address'];} throws an error

Comment: is there a more optimized way to do so? if I have a json list of more than 20 names and i need to display their value, but I don't know if which one of them will be returned in the json, it could be ony one or 3 or 10 or all 20 of them, should I repeat the same for each one of them, for example: `if data[0].name : console.log(data[0].name);  if data[0].adress : console.log(data[0].adress); ..`

Comment: could `data[0].[0]` work, to access `name`? Looking at it like an array.

Answer (score 32):

The JSON you are receiving is in string. You have to convert it into JSON object
You have commented the most important line of code

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Or if you are using jQuery

```
data = $.parseJSON(data)
```

Comment: even on uncommenting the line i receive undefined

Comment: That is because your JSON is an array. Try data[0].name instead of data.name. And make sure you access property not value i.e. data[0].name (property) instead of what you are doing in your question data.myName(which is value)

Answer (score 16):

If you response is like `{'customer':{'first_name':'John','last_name':'Cena'}}`

```
var d = JSON.parse(response);
alert(d.customer.first_name); // contains "John"
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, If I wanted to extract 'customer' how would I do that where customer is the actual thing I want. In my case I want to extract aboutme.jpg that below as a string              b'{"_id":"2","_rev":"5-760e627e77645e960c5cc40ea6cf03a2","_attachments":{"aboutme.jpg":{"content_type":"image/jpeg","revpos":3,"digest":"md5-mG5uU4IRGuY/f9PbZ8AIbQ==","length":98831,"stub":true}}}\n'

Answer (score 7):

You should do

```
alert(data[0].name); //Take the property name of the first array
```

and not

```
 alert(data.myName)
```

jQuery should be able to sniff the dataType for you even if you don't set it so no need for JSON.parse.

fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/H2yN6/

Answer (score 4):

**Try this code..**

```
function (data) {


var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert( json.name );


}
```

Comment: i tried it before and getting an error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'parseJSON'

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try this approach:

```
var  str ="{ "name" : "user"}";
var jsonData = JSON.parse(str);     
console.log(jsonData.name)
//Array Object
str ="[{ "name" : "user"},{ "name" : "user2"}]";
jsonData = JSON.parse(str);     
console.log(jsonData[0].name)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should mention `dataType: 'json'`  in  ajax config and to access that value:

```
data[0].name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a friendly piece of advice. Use something like [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox to inspect your Ajax calls and results.

You may also want to invest some time in understanding a helper library like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), which complements jQuery and gives you 60+ useful functions for manipulating data objects with JavaScript.

Comment: This would be better as a comment.