# Js Object - Getting the Value

Tags: javascript

I have some JSON data - on doing `console.log(json.children[0])` I'm returned:

[image]

Now I'm trying to obtain the item `value` so I can update it.

I'm trying to get the value `console.log(json.children[0].value)` however it keeps returning `undefined`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or mis-understanding?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your JSON string?

Comment: Try the method from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895306/how-to-access-json-object-name-value)
Try setting dataType: 'json' in your request

Comment: @margarita How is that even remotely relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help but notice the fact that the initial log:

> Object {name: "Chocolate", children: Array[2]}

... is completely different to the expanded values shown.

It is worth noting the <kbd>*i*</kbd> mark in the console.

> Object value at left was snapshotted when logged, value below was evaluated just now.

This suggests that when you actually call `console.log(json.children[0])`, it only has the two properties `name` and `children`. The other properties, including `dx`, `dy` and the sought `value`, aren't added until later in the code.

To get these values, you will have to attempt accessing them *after* the code that generates them runs. Of course without seeing more details on your code it's impossible to say when/where that should be, but this is what I have for you with what you've provided.

Comment: Ah - thanks! Got it.