# jquery extract json value

Tags: jquery, json

I got a jquery code.
I process a method and receive a value `custCNFormData`
I want to extract a specific value.
I do the following code.

```
   var custCNFormData = custCNFormSubmit();
   var creditNoteHeader = custCNFormData.get('creditNoteHeader');
    console.log('value:'+creditNoteHeader);
    console.log('cdReference is : '+creditNoteHeader.cdReference);
```

The json message is below

```
 value:
{  
  "customer":{  
      "customerId":"1002"
  },
  "cdReference":"3",
  "invoicenumber":"5" 
}
```

but output is  `undefined`

how do i extract value of `cdReference` ?

Comment: Please show what `custCNFormSubmit()` does and what it returns as per [mcve]

Comment: the method does alot of data processing.   i have posted the value it returns. I need to extract a value from the returned json object

Comment: have a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895306/how-to-access-json-object-name-value

Comment: Then scale it down to a minimal representation of the problem. We have no way to help without a **runnable** [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

depend on your output, try this `creditNoteHeader[1].cdReference`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access json properties by name like below example

```js
var creditNoteHeader =
{  
  customer:{  
      customerId:"1002"
  },
  cdReference:"3",
  invoicenumber:"5" 
}

console.log("CustomerId : " + creditNoteHeader.customer.customerId);
console.log("cdReference : " + creditNoteHeader.cdReference);
console.log("invoicenumber : " + creditNoteHeader.invoicenumber);
```

Comment: There is no JSON shown here. JSON is a string data format

Answer (score 0):

First check your json data is in string  or object format . If string then parse into json.
Then you can extract json data.

`console.log('value:'+creditNoteHeader);`
creditNoteHeader is your object when you concat to string in console.log this will give undefined.