# Get a value from data-actions attribute

Tags: jquery, revolution-slider

This is a revolution slider button.

I would like to get the `"rs-26"` from the `data-actions` attribute of a `div`. How can I get it using jQuery?

`data-actions="[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"rs-26","delay":""}]"`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this.  Without knowing that your action div looks like, I assumed it was something like this:

```
<div id="theDiv" data-actions='[{"event":"click","action":"jumptoslide","slide":"rs-26","delay":""}]'>
    div with content
</div>
```

Then, the jQuery you would want could be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var actions = $("#theDiv").data("actions");
    var theSlide = actions[0].slide;
    console.log('The Slide: ' + theSlide);
});
```

I just used `$(document).ready(function() {` so that it would happen upon page load, but you can use that where you need it.

Here are a few additional resources that might help:

> [How to access JSON Object
>   name/value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895306/how-to-access-json-object-name-value)
>
> [Store JSON object in data attribute in HTML
>   jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542746/store-json-object-in-data-attribute-in-html-jquery)
>
> [How to get the data-id
>   attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)