# Cannot show json data in dropdown list jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am getting json data from my php code something like this :

> {2: "Robert ", 3: "Adem"}

Now i want to show it in dropdown list using jQuery I'm using the following code but 'm getting object in dropdown.

```
jQuery(response).each(function (index, value) {
  jQuery("#name").append(jQuery("<option>").val(value).text(value));
});
```

Comment: simply use `jQuery.each(response ,function(index,value){........` instead of `jQuery(response).each(function(index,value){.....` And no need for `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from doing `JSON.parse()`. `.each()` callback should be applied on `Array` not an `Object`, just convert your response object to `Array` using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), here is a working snippet:

```js
let responseStr = {2:"Robert ", 3:"Adem"}; // <----- Make sure that its an object if its not then you have to do JSON.pares().
console.log(Object.values(responseStr));
jQuery(Object.values(responseStr)).each(function(index,value){
   jQuery('#name').append(jQuery('<option>').val(value).text(value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse them using [$.parseJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) and to retrieve data.

If you want to do without parsing refer below.

[How to access JSON Object name/value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895306/how-to-access-json-object-name-value)

Answer (score 0):

If the response coming from your PHP file is a JSON string then you will have to convert it into a javascript array then iterate it to get your option

use `JSON.parse()`;

```
var options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

jQuery.each( options, function( index, value ) {
   $('#name').append('<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>');
});
```

Comment: but now i'm getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse

Comment: Give it a try now.

Comment: now it not throwing any error but a single object in dropdown is shown, when i console options i get {2: "Rod ", 3: "Adem"}

Comment: Just try to append option with your old approach or append the HTML directly.

Comment: same result is there

Comment: Try it now. Also, console.log(option.length) to know the object count.